# Сделать http(s) запрос к серверу по ip от имени конкретного сайта

Tags: php, bash, hosts

Например 
есть site.com
он висит на 1.1.1.1

Есть тестовый (или клон) сервак 1.1.1.2 
Мне нужно подключится к этому тестовому так, как будто он и есть основной

Да, я знаю про существование файла hosts и в вынде и линуксе, но ползание по этому hosts мне по ряду причин не подходит.

Идеальный для меня вариант - это какая-нибудь bash или php команда, которая по-тупому делает мне то, что мне нужно:

```
$as_url = 'http://site.com/';
$from_ip = '1.1.1.2';
print_site ( $as_url, $from_ip);
```

Comment: curl можно сказать на какой конкретно ip ему обращаться к сайту

Comment: Спасибо! ЭТО ОНО!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

имя сайта при обращении по протоколу *http* передаётся в заголовке `host`.

поэтому вам подойдёт любой http-клиент, которому можно указать заголовок.

```
$ wget --header 'host: site.com' http://1.1.1.2/
$ curl --header 'host: site.com' http://1.1.1.2/
```

и т.п.

---

но если очень хочется, то можно обойтись и возможностями самой программы *bash*:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 5<>/dev/tcp/1.1.1.2/80
cat <&5 &
printf "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nhost: site.ru\r\n\r\n" >&5
```